# Algorithm for setting up new groups with randomized employees in a company for mixed group lunch

Tags: algorithm, graph

Could someone please help suggest an algorithm for the following problem?

### Problem statement for the randomizer script

For mixed group lunches, set up new groups with randomized employees in a company. Set up groups with employees who have not recently had lunch together with USING THE HISTORY LUNCH DATA BELOW.

### INPUT data

1. List of current employee names
2. History data from the past mixed group lunches. Please look at the sample data at the end below.

### OUTPUT data from the randomizer script

New groups with randomized employees.  Set up groups with people who have not had lunch together with RECENTLY.

### Assumptions

- The group sizes in the past varied. To simplify the problem, the future lunches will be groups of 5 people
- Need to consider new employees who just joined and disregard the employees who left the company.

### HISTORY LUNCH DATA from the past mixed group lunches

#### 1/13/2012  -------------

Group A
Jason
James
Kimbery
Joseph
Michael

Group B
Lisa
Kelly
Matthew
Amy

Group C
...

Group …
...

Group X
...

#### 3/23/2013 ————————-----------------------------

Group A
Kelly
Anthony
Tracy

Group B
Susan
Scott
Bryan
Joseph

...

Group Z
...

#### 7/01/2014  ————————-----------------------------

Group A
Jon Michael Mia

Group B
...

Group Y
...

#### 8/10/2014 ————————-----------------------------

Group A
...

Group B
...

Group S
...

———————————————————

Comment: Do I need to use a graph partitioning algorithm?

Comment: Hmm, so there is only one condition, which is the group never has lunch together before?

Comment: Sounds like a coloring problem to me.